# Change the text will_paginate renders

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can change the text that will_paginate shows?

Right now, it renders `Previous ... Next`. I need to put that in french `Précédent ... Suivant`. I checked on google and got this link : http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2010/8/22/revisited-roll-your-own-pagination-links-with-will_paginate-and-rails-3

However, I was wondering if there was an easier way.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can [override the default](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/the-will_paginate-view-helper) of Previous and Next this way:

```
<%= will_paginate @posts, :previous_label => 'Précédent', :next_label => 'Suivant' %>
```

Note: `:previous_label` was called `:prev_label` in versions 2.3.2 and older

Comment: how to use icons instead of text?

Comment: If you wants to use icon instead of text. You can use image tag like this.
`<%= will_paginate @posts, :previous_label => '<img src="/pagination/left-arrow.svg">', :next_label => '<img src="/pagination/right-arrow.svg">' %>`

Answer (score 8):

So you have to ensure that the following is in place:

- Your locale is set to french. This normally depends on the browser your are using. Chrome e.g. uses the locale of the operating system. I have set in `application.rb` the default locale (german for me): `config.i18n.default_locale = :de`
- The directory `config/locales` contains a file `fr.yml` with the following content (there could be more customization):

  ```
  views:
    pagination:
      first: "F"
      previous: "&laquo; Prev"
      next: "Next &raquo;"
      last: "L"
      truncate: "..."
  ```

This works for me in the current version of Rails 3.2.2 with `gem 'will_paginate', '>= 3.0'`.